# Linking Spring project to MySQl database

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I have been trying to access MySQL routines from my Spring project using SimpleJdbcDaoSupport.

I have a class called 'AdminSimpleMessageManager', which implements the interface 'AdminMessageManager'.

'AdminSimpleMessageManager' has an instance of the class 'AdminSimpleJdbcMessageDao', which implements the interface 'AdminMessageDao'.

AdminSimpleJdbcMessageDao has the following method:

```
public class AdminSimpleJdbcMessageDao extends SimpleJdbcDaoSupport implements AdminMessageDao {

public int addMessage(String from, String message) {
    return getJdbcTemplate().queryForInt("call insert_contact_message(?, ?)", from, message);
}
```

}

I have included the following in my application context:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/OctagonDB"/>
</bean>

<bean id="adminMessageManager" class="Managers.AdminSimpleMessageManager">
    <property name="adminMessageDao" ref="adminMessageDao"/>
</bean>

<bean id="adminMessageDao" class="Managers.dao.AdminSimpleJdbcMessageDao">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

but I feel there are a few important lines missing. I get the error

> FAIL - Deployed application at context path /NewWebsite but context failed to start

among other things.

Comment: Is there a stack trace somewhere in your logs?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't load your application context.  Find the logs and see what you did wrong.  What about your web.xml?  Did you tell Spring where to find the context XML?

Comment: I have added nothing regarding MySQL into my web.xml, but I have noticed I spelt the database name wrong. The error I get now is 'Could not get JDBC Connection - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver', when the insert method is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include a [MySQL JDBC driver](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/) in your classpath. Furthermore you should update the config of the driver class name to `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`. `org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver` is only retained for backwards compatibility.

However, since you seem to be loading the datasource through JNDI I guess the driver JAR should be in your container (which provides the datasource through JNDI) rather than in your app's `WEB-INF/lib`?

Comment: Thanks, that solved part of the problem. I now get the error "java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data.". Do you know if this is due to my routine now returning anything? The routine being called is simply this: "INSERT INTO contact_messages (`author`, `message`, `date_sent`) VALUES (_author, _message, NOW());"

Comment: Don't know...for the sake of clarity and in order to better help others looking for similar problems/exceptions I suggest you accept my answer and post a new question for this. It'll be a lot easier to describe now that Spring and driver issues are out of the way.